# Python 3 / Django 2, Passing a dictionary value to form field before saving

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to get my app to use a serial number, entered on a form, to compare to a dictionary and update a product field on a form before saving. Here's the details:

- Dictionary is two columns, 'Product Code', and 'Product'
- The first three digits of the Serial number entered on the form will match to the Product Code in the dictionary.
- Once the user submits the form, I want it to evaluate the serial number's first three digits, compare it to the dictionary keys, then change the 'product' form field to the dict['Product'] before saving the form.

Here is my view:

```
def create(request):
#Page with input form to submit new records
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RecordForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        sn = request.POST.get('serial')
        with open('prodlist.csv') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                if sn[0:2] in row['Product Code']:
                    form.fields['product'].update = row['Product']
                else:
                    pass
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/tracker/all/')
else:
    form = RecordForm()
return render(request, 'tracker/form2.html', {'form': form}, RequestContext(request))
```

With this, I'm geting a key error for the 'product' piece. Is there a way to pass a value to a form field after it is submitted?

Update:

I've added the product field to the form itself in forms.py:

```
class RecordForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Record
    fields = ['serial',
              'ticket',
              'product',
              'eng_date',
              'customer',
              'details',
              'owner',
              'status',
              'seed_num'
             ]
    widgets = {
            'eng_date': DateInput(),
            }
```

And I've changed the `form.fields['product'].update = row['Product']` line to `form.cleaned_data['product'] = row['Product']`. and added an else: clause to write something anyway, in case it doesn't find the serial: `else: form.cleaned_data['product'] = '5678'`

Here's the full view:

```
def create(request):
#Page with input form to submit new records
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RecordForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        sn = request.POST.get('serial')
        with open('prodlist.csv') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                if sn[0:2] in row['Product Code']:
                    form.cleaned_data['product'] = row['Product']
                else:
                    form.cleaned_data['product'] = '5678'
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/tracker/all/')
else:
    form = RecordForm()
return render(request, 'tracker/form2.html', {'form': form}, RequestContext(request))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What does your RecordForm look like? Does it include a 'product' field in it that isn't getting entered? or is it not part of the form, just the model?

Comment: Hi Scott,

I'm using the Meta class on a model form, and I just realized that product is not included. That must be the issue? I'll have to test it in a bit, but here's what I have at the moment:

`class RecordForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Record
        fields = ['serial',
                  'ticket',
                  'eng_date',
                  'customer',
                  'details',
                  'owner',
                  'status',
                  'seed_num'
                 ]
        widgets = {
                'eng_date': DateInput(),
     }`

Comment: I've updated the question with RecordForm and what's been tried so far. Behavior is currently no error, but the product field is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
form.cleaned_data['product'] = row['Product']
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! That got rid of the key error, but it doesn't seem to be saving. I also tried passing that line to the else: with a value of '1234' which didn't get saved either.
EDIT: hit enter before i was done
I'm still playing with it. Do i need to add like a .update or .initial to the end of the form.cleaned_data['product']?

Comment: I've updated the question if you have any other ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working! Had to use `obj = form.save(commit=false)`, then pass the value to that as `obj.product` , and then ust `obj.save()`. Here is the view as it stands:

```
def create(request):
#Page with input form to submit new records
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RecordForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        sn = request.POST.get('serial')
        with open('prodlist.csv') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                if sn[0:2] in row['Product Code']:
                    obj = form.save(commit=False)
                    obj.product = row['Product']
                    obj.save()
                    break
                else:
                    pass
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/tracker/all/')
else:
    form = RecordForm()
return render(request, 'tracker/form2.html', {'form': form}, RequestContext(request))
```